# Create Bot to automate banking tasks with python

Tags: python, automation

I would like to create a bot with python to automate some banking tasks. The bot should be able to do the following.

1. Log into an online banking website (e.g. Chase, CapitalOne, etc.) and download/save recent transaction activity which is given as a CSV file.
2. Compare contents of CSV file with a Google Sheets doc.
3. Based on results of previous comparison, make edits to the Google Sheets doc and the CSV file.
4. Transfer the updated CSV file to a remote location.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Show what you have done now. StackOverflow is not a code writing service provider.

Comment: Your bank definitely will not like it if you do this

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! It is encouraged for you to post what code you have came up with so far so we can help you with specific problems. This is a very general question.

I will do my best to point you in the right direction while using Google Chrome:

First, you will want to use inspect element and look over the network logs while performing certain tasks on the website along with also taking notes of your cookies.

By doing this, your goal should be finding out how you can access your recent transactions using requests and cookies. This will likely be difficult as you are dealing with a banks website and it is likely very secure.

After figuring this out, you will want to look into the requests library as well as the Sheets API for Python. Use the requests library to log into the bank and gather the transactions. Use the sheets API to handle everything required in Google Sheets.

Another option which would be a lot easier would be using Selenium along with a headless browser: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/